# I am facing a problem in the frontend index blade

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am facing a problem with the frontend index blade. For product details, I am passing the subcategory name from the subcategory model. It worked perfectly, but when I deleted the subcategory name from the database, at that time I am facing this error. please help me.

**Error:**
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "subcategory_name" on null (View: F:\laravel\covid\resources\views\frontend\index.blade.php)

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

**Code here:**

{{ App\Models\Category::find($product->category_id)->category_name }}

Answer (score 0):

Please write your question with right format , and submit your full controller/view code

Comment: Please see again

Comment: $cat_name = App\Models\Category::select('category_name')->where('id', $product->category_id)->get();

try this way